# Calculate amount of value changes in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a database for example:

```
 { "_id": ObjectId("54575132a8269c77675ace49"),"power": false, "time": 1415008560000}
 { "_id": ObjectId("54575132a8269c77675ace50"),"power": true, "time": 1415008570000}
 { "_id": ObjectId("54575132a8269c77675ace51"),"power": false, "time": 1415008580000}
 { "_id": ObjectId("54575132a8269c77675ace52"),"power": false, "time": 1415008590000}
 { "_id": ObjectId("54575132a8269c77675ace53"),"power": true, "time": 1415008600000}
 { "_id": ObjectId("54575132a8269c77675ace54"),"power": false, "time": 1415008610000}
```

How can I calculate amount of **power** changes from **true** to **false** and opposite?

I could iterate through all entries and increase some variable if previous value is different than actual, but how to do this in mongo?

For this example result should be 4

Comment: What is your expected sample output?

Comment: @JMichal: Please see my revised approach, which should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the aggregation framework to do this:

```javascript
db.yourCollection.aggregate({ $group:{ _id:"$power", count:{$sum:1} } })
```

which should give you the following result:

```javascript
{_id:true,count:2}
{_id:false, count:4}
```

By subtracting the difference of those two values from the total document count (`db.yourCollection.count()`), you should have the number of state changes:

```javascript
var cursor = db.yourCollection.aggregate({ $group:{ _id:"$power", count:{$sum:1} } });
var count = db.yourCollection.count();
var changes = count - Math.abs(cursor[0].count - cursor[1].count);
```

### EDIT: Revised approach

As per @JohhnyHK's sharp eye, he found a problem with the above. All kudos, upvotes and alike to him.

#### Calculating the number of changes

In order to calculate the changes even for large collections efficiently, with the given constraints, once could use map/reduce to count the changes, which should be pretty efficient even for very large collections.

```javascript
var numberOfStateChanges = db.yourCollection.mapReduce(
  // Mapping function
  function(){
    // Since in the sample data, there is no reasonable
    // field for a key, we use an artificial one: 0
    emit(0,this.power);
  },
  // Reduce function
  function(key,values){
    // The initial number of changes is 0
    var changes=0;

    // Our initial state, which does not count towards the changes,...
    var state = values[0];

    // ... hence we start to compare with the second item in the values array
    for (var idx=1; idx < value.length; idx++){

      // In case the current state is different from
      // the one we are comparing with it, we have a state change
      if(value[idx] != state) {
        //... which we count...
        changes +=1;
        // ...and save.
        state=value[idx]
      }
    }

    return changes;
  },
  {
    // We make sure the values are fed into the map function in the correct order
    sort:{time:1},
    // and return it directly instead of putting it into a collection, so we can process it
    out:{inline:1}
   }
).results[0].value
```

Now `numberOfStateChanges` holds the correct number of state changes.

#### Note

In order to have this map/reduce to be processed efficiently, we need an index on the field we are sorting by, `time`:

```javascript
db.yourCollection.ensureIndex({time:1})
```

Comment: This doesn't count changes.  The result should be 4, not 2.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow didn't see that part.  But it still doesn't count changes because it doesn't consider the order.  If you've got 3 `false` docs and 3 `true` docs you could have anything between 1 and 5 changes depending on their order.

Comment: Which is correct. The way I have written it  only considers the case when the state is the same two consecutive times. I will edit my answer accordingly. As far as I can see it, m/r is the only scalable way to do it, then.

Comment: @JohnnyHK: Requesting revision.

Comment: Looks great now, Markus.

Comment: how much memory will it consume for a few millions of entries? Are there some limits for amount of entries in this array?

Comment: check this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#mapreduce-map-cmd